# arrowhead rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, rotating

I want the arrowhead to look more natural as opposed to goofy (which is the present state)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new, decorations.markings, calc, fadings,
decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\newcommand{\AxisRotator}[1][rotate=0] {%
  \tikz \draw[x = .5em, y = 1.25em, line width = .2ex, -latex, #1] (0,0)  arc (-150:150:.5 and .5);%                                                   
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .75]
    \draw (-2,0) -- (-3,1.5);
    \draw (2,0) -- (3,1.5);
    \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[-latex] (0,.75) -- (0,2);
    \draw (0,1.5) node {\AxisRotator[rotate = -90]};
    \begin{scope}[yshift = .25cm]
      \clip (-2.5,1) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,.25) -- (-2.5,.25) -- cycle;
      \draw (0,1) ellipse (2.75cm and .5cm);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps using a decoration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new, decorations.markings, calc, fadings,
decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\newcommand{\AxisRotator}[1][rotate=0]{%
  \tikz[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{latex}}}]\draw[x = .5em, y = 2.75em, line width = .2ex,#1,postaction=decorate] (0,0)  arc (-150:150:.45 and .5) -- ++(-95:2pt);%                                                   
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .75]
    \draw (-2,0) -- (-3,1.5);
    \draw (2,0) -- (3,1.5);
    \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[-latex] (0,.75) -- (0,2);
    \draw (0,1.5) node {\AxisRotator[rotate = -90]};
    \begin{scope}[yshift = .25cm]
      \clip (-2.5,1) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,.25) -- (-2.5,.25) -- cycle;
      \draw (0,1) ellipse (2.75cm and .5cm);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison purposes, here's the result with the original code in the question:

[image]

And here's the result for various angles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new, decorations.markings, calc, fadings,
decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}

\newcommand{\AxisRotator}[1][rotate=0] {%
  \tikz[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{latex}}}]\draw[x = .5em, y = 2.75em, line width = .2ex,#1,postaction=decorate] (0,0)  arc (-150:150:.45 and .5) -- ++(-95:2pt);%                                                   
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .75]
\foreach \angle[count=\xi] in {0,45,...,315}
  \draw (0,1.5) node at (0,1.5*\xi) {\AxisRotator[rotate = \angle]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `-- ++(-95:2pt)` at the end of the arc path just to extend it a little allowing the arrow to be well positioned.

Comment: I don't think that is much better.

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer. Perhaps it is a little better now?

Comment: can you explain `++(-100:1pt)`?

Comment: @dustin sure! It's just a trick: I added a little line segment at the end of the arc path to move the arrow tip a little.

Comment: FWIW metapost arrows follow the curve a little better (mp actually curves the arrowheads).  For arrowheads where the curve is too tight they look goofy in a completely different way!  So if you're interested in a metapost (or asymptote, or pstricks) solution, then indicate that, and several advocates of their favourite graphics language will leap to your aid.

Answer (score 3):

`arrows.meta` library (`TikZ 3.0`, section 16) introduces more flexibility for drawing arrows. This version also presents `pics` which help to avoid drawing `tikzpictures` inside `tikzpictures`. Next code combines both tools.

The `AxisRotator` pic is placed according ellipse's center (which has been defined by trial and error).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\tikzset{
    pics/AxisRotator/.style={
    code={
        \draw [x=1em, y=1em, line width=.2ex, -{Latex[length=.5em, quick]},rotate=#1] (-.25,-.7) arc (-150:165:.3375 and 1.375);
    }},
    pics/AxisRotator/.default=0
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .75]
    \draw (-2,0) -- (-3,1.5);
    \draw (2,0) -- (3,1.5);
    \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[-latex] (0,.75) -- (0,2);
    \draw (0,1.5) pic {AxisRotator=-90};
    \begin{scope}[yshift = .25cm]
      \clip (-2.5,1) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,.25) -- (-2.5,.25) -- cycle;
      \draw (0,1) ellipse (2.75cm and .5cm);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]